# ExpressionEngine versions and MYSQL support

Tags: mysql

Does anyone have a link to the MYSQL version supported by different versions of ExpressionEngine? I need to upgrade the MYSQL version on a server containing several EE sites.
Thanks,
Clive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dig through the various [documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html) flavours. From this I can see :

- EE 2.10 = MySQL 5.0.3 or newer
- EE 2.9  = MySQL 5.0.3 or newer
- EE 2.8  = MySQL 5.0.3 or newer

How far back do you need to go?? Using the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140715000000*/https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html) I can see older version requirments :

- EE 2.7 = MySQL 5.0.3+ (Feb 22 2014)
- EE 2.6 = MySQL 5.0.3+ (Apr 25 2013)
- EE 2.5 = MySQL 4.1+ (Nov 29 2012) <== this is where the current documentation site started.

You need to go back any further?? Ok then! [Wayback @ expressionengine.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20121028085240/http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/requirements.html)

- EE 2.4 = MySQL 4.1+ (Jan 26 2012)
- EE 2.3 = MySQL 4.1+ (Oct 24 2011)

More?? You want *MOREEEE*? (Oliver Twist reference) [EE2.2Wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20110829030020/http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/)

- EE 2.2 = MySQL 4.1+ (~Jun 24 2011)
- EE 2.1 = MySQL 4.1+ (~Oct 15 2010)
- EE 2.0 = Beta, if your running sites on this, well....

Comment: Nah, this is good. Looks like I just need to upgrade MySQL and see how it goes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're upgrading to MySQL 5.7.5+ you'll need EE 2.11.0+